# got android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException on note4

Tags: android

an app on the wild(`running on note4:SM-N910F`) reported the following crash:

```
android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Fatal error 4097, details: Allocation::Allocation, alloc failureTRACK TRACE: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Fatal error 4097, details: Allocation::Allocation, alloc failure
    at android.renderscript.RenderScript$MessageThread.run(RenderScript.java:1143)
```

Tried to Google it, with no success , anybody met this `Exception` before?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

4097 is a fatal driver error for RenderScript.

Comment: sure,what details to you need?

Comment: What app is this? Any other information in the logcat? What does that app try to do with RenderScript? Is it your app or a third-party app (i.e. can you share some source)?

Comment: Hey stephen, i will try to look at my logcat and i'll share here , Thanks