# android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException Fatal error 4097

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm getting the following crash from renderscript on android:
[image]

100% of the crashes are on android 11 and 96% of the crashes are on Samsung devices. I removed all instances of renderscript, but this crash is still happening so maybe it's in one of my dependencies.

I found this [got android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException on note4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725253/got-android-renderscript-rsruntimeexception-on-note4) which says that 4097 means a fatal driver error, but doesn't give any details on how to fix it.

Does anyone know how I can fix this crash?

UPDATE: when I search for "renderscript" in my app nothing comes up unless I put it on scope and then there's a bunch of references to it. I don't understand where they're coming from though
[image]

UPDATE: To be clear, I have removed all references to renderscript from my app but it seems like one or multiple of my dependencies are still using it. I need help isolating these dependencies. Something called android-30 is using renderscript. Is this the api 30 library or something? And then something called support/v8 is using renderscript. Is this the support library? (I do have support library enabled)

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @HamidYusifli I added more details, does that help?

Answer (score 4):

[Migrate from RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate)

> RenderScript APIs are deprecated starting in Android 12. They will
> continue to function, but we expect that device and component
> manufacturers will stop providing hardware acceleration support over
> time.

It seems to be a vendors issue (Driver issue)

Fatal error 4097: **RS_ERROR_FATAL_UNKNOWN = 0x1000**

```
static class MessageThread extends Thread {
        RenderScript mRS;
        boolean mRun = true;
        int[] mAuxData = new int[2];

        static final int RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_NONE = 0;
        static final int RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_EXCEPTION = 1;
        static final int RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_RESIZE = 2;
        static final int RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_ERROR = 3;
        static final int RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_USER = 4;
        static final int RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_NEW_BUFFER = 5;

        static final int RS_ERROR_FATAL_DEBUG = 0x0800;
        static final int RS_ERROR_FATAL_UNKNOWN = 0x1000;

        MessageThread(RenderScript rs) {
            super("RSMessageThread");
            mRS = rs;

        }

        public void run() {
            // This function is a temporary solution.  The final solution will
            // used typed allocations where the message id is the type indicator.
            int[] rbuf = new int[16];
            mRS.nContextInitToClient(mRS.mContext);
            while(mRun) {
                rbuf[0] = 0;
                int msg = mRS.nContextPeekMessage(mRS.mContext, mAuxData);
                int size = mAuxData[1];
                int subID = mAuxData[0];

                if (msg == RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_USER) {
                    if ((size>>2) >= rbuf.length) {
                        rbuf = new int[(size + 3) >> 2];
                    }
                    if (mRS.nContextGetUserMessage(mRS.mContext, rbuf) !=
                        RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_USER) {
                        throw new RSDriverException("Error processing message from RenderScript.");
                    }

                    if(mRS.mMessageCallback != null) {
                        mRS.mMessageCallback.mData = rbuf;
                        mRS.mMessageCallback.mID = subID;
                        mRS.mMessageCallback.mLength = size;
                        mRS.mMessageCallback.run();
                    } else {
                        throw new RSInvalidStateException("Received a message from the script with no message handler installed.");
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (msg == RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_ERROR) {
                    String e = mRS.nContextGetErrorMessage(mRS.mContext);

                    // Throw RSRuntimeException under the following conditions:
                    //
                    // 1) It is an unknown fatal error.
                    // 2) It is a debug fatal error, and we are not in a
                    //    debug context.
                    // 3) It is a debug fatal error, and we do not have an
                    //    error callback.
                    if (subID >= RS_ERROR_FATAL_UNKNOWN ||
                        (subID >= RS_ERROR_FATAL_DEBUG &&
                         (mRS.mContextType != ContextType.DEBUG ||
                          mRS.mErrorCallback == null))) {
                        throw new RSRuntimeException("Fatal error " + subID + ", details: " + e);
                    }

                    if(mRS.mErrorCallback != null) {
                        mRS.mErrorCallback.mErrorMessage = e;
                        mRS.mErrorCallback.mErrorNum = subID;
                        mRS.mErrorCallback.run();
                    } else {
                        android.util.Log.e(LOG_TAG, "non fatal RS error, " + e);
                        // Do not throw here. In these cases, we do not have
                        // a fatal error.
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (msg == RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_NEW_BUFFER) {
                    if (mRS.nContextGetUserMessage(mRS.mContext, rbuf) !=
                        RS_MESSAGE_TO_CLIENT_NEW_BUFFER) {
                        throw new RSDriverException("Error processing message from RenderScript.");
                    }
                    long bufferID = ((long)rbuf[1] << 32L) + ((long)rbuf[0] & 0xffffffffL);
                    Allocation.sendBufferNotification(bufferID);
                    continue;
                }

                // 2: teardown.
                // But we want to avoid starving other threads during
                // teardown by yielding until the next line in the destructor
                // can execute to set mRun = false
                try {
                    sleep(1, 0);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MessageThread exiting.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not helpful. I already removed all references to render script from my app, so there's no migration needed.

Comment: I updated my question, it seems like some of my dependencies might be using renderscript, but I can't figure out how to tell which ones are doing it